# Error returning promise from Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli-mirage

I am working on my first Ember app and got it to display the way I wanted with the route returning a static JSON object from `model()`:

```
element: {
  name: "First Element",
  divisions: [{
    name: "First Division",
    sets: [{name: "Set 1"},{name: "Set 2"},{name: "Set 3"}]
  }, {
    name: "Second Division",
    sets: [{name: "Set 1"},{name: "Set 2"},{name: "Set 3"}]
  }]
}
```

Now I am trying to refactor to use Ember Data + Mirage and having an awful time.

Here’s my `index.js` route

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.find('element', 1);
    },
```

If I set up my Mirage `config.js` like this:

```
  this.get('/elements', function() {
    return {
      elements: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'First Element',
            divisions: [1, 2]
          }
      ]
    }
  });
```

then I get this error:

```
Your Ember app tried to GET '/elements/1', but there was no route defined to handle this request.
```

If I set up my Mirage `config.js` like this:

```
  this.get('/elements/1', function() {
    return {
       id: 1,
       name: 'First Element',
       divisions: [1, 2]
    }
  });
```

then I get this error:

```
22:46:40.883 "Error while processing route: index" "Assertion Failed: normalizeResponse must return a valid JSON API document:
    * One or more of the following keys must be present: "data", "errors", "meta"." "EmberError@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:25582:15
```

**EDIT:**

So this isn't a solution to the problem as stated but it got me past this.  I gave up on Pretender and started again creating an actual Rails server according to this excellent tutorial: http://emberigniter.com/modern-bridge-ember-and-rails-5-with-json-api/

I was able to do everything I wanted this way and if I ever want to make this a production app, I'm a lot closer.

Comment: Your API response seems to be invalid for ember-data. Can you update your post with what your server sends? Ember-data expects data to be formatted as described here : http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/

Comment: Can you show your router ? You are probably missing a route

Comment: What's going on here is that I have a single element (right now) which contains many divisions, each of which contain many sets.  When I had this working with the static JSON object, I used {{#each in my .hbs template to list out each division, and within that division each set.  So the model for my template is an element.

Comment: Do you use custom adapter or something? Also try removing `divisions: [1, 2]` from config.js and see if it eliminates error.

Comment: So, if you look [here](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-top-level). The top level attribute in your Mirage response needs to be either: "data", "errors", or "meta". The first step is to wrap your "element(s)" attribute inside of a "data" attribute. That didn't solve the problem for me, but it's a logical first step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the issue is that you aren't actually adhering to the [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) specification. You can solve this by reading Mirage's page on [how to conform](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.1.x/working-with-json-api/).

Essentially you need to either be returning an object at the top level of your JSON response in the case of a `GET /foo/1` call. You'll also need to change your "elements" attribute to "data" for `GET /foo` and that should do the trick. Right now there isn't a simple, re-usable way to do this Mirage out of the box. The best bet right now for both issues is to use the solution presented in this [issue](https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage/issues/223#issuecomment-137539848).

Answer (score 0):

ember error `normalizeResponse must return a valid JSON API document`
can be fixed in three ways

#### return a valid JSONAPI response

see your error message:

> normalizeResponse must return a valid JSON API document:
> * One or more of the following keys must be present: "data", "errors", "meta".

```js
  this.get('/elements/1', function() {
    return {
      data: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'First Element',
        divisions: [1, 2]
      }
    }
  });
```

see also https://jsonapi.org/examples/

#### normalize all responses

```js
// app/serializers/application.js

import EmberData from "ember-data";

export default EmberData.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
    normalizeResponse() {
        return {
            data: this._super(...arguments),
        };
    },
    //normalize(){},
    //serialize(){},
    // ...
});
```

problem: error handling

by wrapping all responses in `{ data: ... }`, they never return errors

on errors, the response should be

```js
  this.get('/elements/1', function() {
    return {
      errors: [
        {
          id: 12345,
          title: 'title for error #12345'
        }
      ]
    }
  });
```

see also https://jsonapi.org/format/#error-objects

#### replace JSONAPI with REST

```sh
sed -i 's/JSONAPISerializer/RESTSerializer/g' app/serializers/*.js
sed -i 's/JSONAPIAdapter/RESTAdapter/g' app/adapters/*.js
```

ember docs: [adapters](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/customizing-adapters/) and [serializers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/customizing-serializers/)

duplicate: [How can ember application be integrated to use with json-server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022200/how-can-ember-application-be-integrated-to-use-with-json-server)